# Set The Visibility of The Whole Box

Tags: java, android, xml, android-constraintlayout

So in my app I have a registration form used to register other users. In my app I have 3 ranks (Admin, Patient, HCP). In the 'New HCP' form I want to hide something that is in my .xml file for the TextView. I am well aware of `setVisibilty(View.GONE);` but this doesn't work for my options because I have the boxes in a **Constraint Layout**.

My Question is:

**How do I hide the whole box including its contents?**

I tried this (but it only hid the contents and left the drawable box behind:

```
TextView consent_TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Register_text_Activity_consent);
        consent_TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TextView remind_TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Register_text_Activity_remind);
        remind_TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Please remember that I want to change this in Java not XML because if I do it in XML I will hide the box for everyone**. Thanks!

Comment: is the whole box a constraint layout? and if so, do you have a reference to it?      i.e box = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.box);
box.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: yeah it's all inside the constraint layout. No i haven't a reference to it. problem is I have used the box in the whole form so hiding it with a reference like that I would imagine hides it for all the other uses in the form

Comment: is it possible for u to implement 3 boxes? this way u can have a box correspond to the 3 ranks and u can choose to hide individual boxes if u don't need them to be visible.

Comment: I don't quite understand how your layout works but you can get a reference to your ConstraintLayout via `View#getParent()` and then set its visibility. If you're reusing it somewhere else in the same screen, just give it an id, bind it and set its visibility.

Comment: @GabrielCosta whats the code I give under the constraint layout to give it an id?

Comment: @GhaziSaghir you can set the id of a View through XML (better option because Android generates an unique id automatically) with the field android:id or you can set it programatically via `View#setId()`, providing an unique id for the view.

Comment: It will be better if you can share your xml code too so we can help you. What is the "box" thing ? Is it a nested layout group ?

Comment: @GabrielCosta That worked thanks! Post your answers into a comment so I can mark this post as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can get a reference to the box you want to set the visibility either through [`View#getParent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent()) or you can set its id programatically via [`View#setId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)), bind it and set its visibility.